# Style 3D button with Simple L-Shaped Bezel? (aka. Old-Style BezelButton)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

This is what I want my UWP Button to look like using a "Style" block:

[image]

Light on the top-Left Corner, Dark on the Lower-Right Corner
Its not a subjective question.  I'm asking for how to make the most generic, button style that everybody has been using for years, but is missing from UWP, and implemented in the simplest way possible without too much XAML code to drag around.

When I put Buttons side by side in a UWP Grid Container the buttons always look bad.  How do you minimal style the buttons so that they look good? See Above Picture. I can place them together with zero spacing and it still looks good with definition between the buttons.

I thought this looked good for a time (see below). But after awhile, I decided, I preferred the traditional 3D button look where the Left and Right Border overlap between buttons with margin=1...instead of doubling up to 2 pixels instead... or maybe that was an optical illusion of some configuration of Properties that I have yet to find...

```
<Page ... Margin="1">
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"  Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Button1"/>
        <Button Content="B2"/>
        <Button Content="XYZ"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Comment: "Looking bad" and "looking good" are subjective measurements. So this is a opinion based question, wich will propably be locked as such.

Comment: Here's the default button style template for Windows 10: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299109.aspx.  That's so deeply nested that i have no idea how to change border to 3D bezel border.

Answer (score 2):

You were pretty close, to mimic the style you're looking for, you can just adjust the `BorderThickness` property to be `0,0,1,1`:

```
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"  Value="0,0,1,1"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
    </Style>
```

This gives you this look:

[image: Buttons with 3D look]

Comment: ahhh!!! Thanks, I've been wondering for year how to do that... I changed the Margin up a bit to get the effect a little bit closer:              <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,1,0,0"/>

Answer (score 0):

Based on Michael Hawker's Answer, I created a Button with a Bezel.

```
public class BezelButton : Button
{
    public BezelButton()
    {
        Margin = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 0);
        BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 2, 2);
        BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
        Content = "Hello";
    }
}

public class HamburgerButton : BezelButton
{
    public HamburgerButton()
    {
        // Default Font Height of Button
        double H = (double)Button.FontSizeProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(double)).DefaultValue;

        double A = H / 5;

        GeometryCollection DataHamburger = new GeometryCollection
    {
        new RectangleGeometry {Rect = new Rect{X = 0, Y = 0*A,  Width = 20, Height = A/2 }},
        new RectangleGeometry {Rect = new Rect{X = 0, Y = 2*A,  Width = 20, Height = A/2 }},
        new RectangleGeometry {Rect = new Rect{X = 0, Y = 4*A,  Width = 20, Height = A/2 }},
    };

        Path PathHamburger = new Path
        {
            Fill    = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray),
            Stroke  = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray),
            StrokeThickness = 1.0,
            Height  = H,
            Margin = new Thickness(4.5), // <==??? HOW TO AUTOMATICALLY CALCULATE??
            Data = new GeometryGroup { Children = DataHamburger }
        };

        Content = PathHamburger;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Way to Create a Button with the classic GUI 3D Bezel is to Nest Two Borders inside of each other with the button inside.

```
    <Border Padding= "2,2,0,0"
            BorderThickness= "0,0,2,2" 
            BorderBrush= "DarkGray"
           Background= "AntiqueWhite">
        <Border Background= "White" >
            <Button Content= "Hello" />
        </Border>
    </Border>
```

The outer Border creates the Top-Left Bezel, and the Bottom-Right Bezel, where the color of Top-Left Bezel is set by Background of the Border Component. The inner border is used to erase this Background back to White because UWP bleeds the background through to the button that is on top.

The above can be used as a bases of a style template for a Button.

An alternative implementation using Grid to Overlay the same cell:

```
<Grid>
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,2,2"
            BorderBrush="DarkGray"/>
    <Border BorderThickness="2,2,0,0"
            BorderBrush="AntiqueWhite"/>
    <Button Content="Hello"/>
</Grid>
```

This also can be implemented using a Style Button Template.

Here's a Simple 3D Bezel Button Style Template that still needs a little bit of work to get the Mouse Over and Button Click States to work:

```
<Page
    x:Class="GridNineExperiment.BlankPage2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:GridNineExperiment"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Border BorderThickness="0,0,2,2"
                                  BorderBrush="DarkGray"/>
                            <Border BorderThickness="2,2,0,0"
                                  BorderBrush="AntiqueWhite"/>

                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                               Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                               ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                               ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                               Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                               HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                               VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                               AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

        </Style>

    </Page.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Hello1"/>
            <Button Content="HiYa1"/>
            <Button Content="HiYa1"/>
            </StackPanel>    
        <Button Content="Hello2"/>
        <Button Content="Hello3"/>
        <Button Content="Hello4"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Comment: I was thinking of this too :).  Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Here's what it looks like]

```
<!-- UWP 3D Button Template: This one has MouseOver, Click States-->
<!-- Add-Project=>Resource Dictionary=>FileName: Button1.Xaml" -->
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:GridNineExperiment">

    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" 
          Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" 
          Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" 
          Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" 
          Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" 
          Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" 
          Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">

                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                   <Storyboard>
                                   <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                   <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame 
                                      KeyTime="0" 
                                      Value="Red"/>
                                   </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                   </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                   <Storyboard>
                                   <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                   <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame 
                                     KeyTime="0" 
                                     Value="Aqua"/>
                                   </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                   </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                  <Storyboard>
                                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                  Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame 
                                    KeyTime="0" 
                                    Value="Grey"/>
                                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                  </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,2,2"
                                  BorderBrush="DarkGray"/>
                        <Border BorderThickness="2,2,0,0"
                                  BorderBrush="AntiqueWhite"/>

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Here's an Example of how to use it:

```
<Page ...>

    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Button1.Xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition 
                    IsStaggeringEnabled="True"
                    FromHorizontalOffset="300"
                    FromVerticalOffset="300"/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Hello1"/>
            <Button Content="Hello2"/>
            <Button Content="Hello3"/>
        </StackPanel>    
        <Button Content="Hello2"/>
        <Button Content="Hello3"/>
        <Button Content="Hello4"/>
        <Rectangle Width="200" Height="100"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```